# TFS 2018 - Error MSB1008 (build using VS)

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I have an Installed instance of TFS 2015 where I had configured a build using VS.
Everything is working.

In this instance I have configured the build like this:

[image]

I installed TFS 2018 in another machine and I am trying to create the some build.
I configured TFS 2018 like this:
[image]

[image]

I don't know why but even though I kept the same build config (as in TFS 2015) I am getting some error:

```
 MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
 Switch: TFS2018\Agent1\_work\3\a
 For switch syntax, type "MSBuild /help"
 Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Can you help me with this?
How can I fix this error?

EDIT: Here goes my Nuget Restore config.
[image]

Comment: What is the get sources step and the file hierarchy?

Comment: What do you mean by the file hierarchy?

Comment: all the files you try to build (how much .sln, how much .csproj)

Comment: I believe its one .sln with some projects (14 I think). TOmorrow I will confirm this

Comment: I've already placed a screenshot (above) with my nuget restore properties. Regarding the file hierarchy I can confirm that I have a .sln file and 14 projects.

Answer (score 3):

This error  `MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified` usually caused because of the space in arguments, but not quoted.

Since the path contains spaces (between `Agents` and `TFS2018`, see your error logs), the `TFS2018` part is considered a new argument and MSBuild doesn't know what to do with it.

So modify your MSBuild Arguments, put the path directory to your file in quotation marks (") to indicate the directory is one argument, then try again.

```
/p:OutDir="$(build.stagingDirectory)" /p:UesWPP_CopyWebApplication=true /p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=false
```